# Find count of second max consecutive letter from the string

Tags: python, regex, count, word-frequency

I want to find the value of second most consecutive occurrence of Letter "C" from given string

st = 
'SSSSEEEECCCCEE**CCCCCCCCC**SSSSEEECCCCSSSSSSSEEESS**CCCCCCC**SEESSSSCCCCCCSSEEEE'

In above string first bold "C" are most consecutive "C"s in a streak. I want to find the second streak. It may be the same length as that of the first.

I have following code :

```
st = 'SSSSEEEECCCCEECCCCCCCCCSSSSEEECCCCSSSSSSSEEESSCCCCCCCSEESSSSCCCCCCSSEEEE'
import re
print "counts_of_C :",list(len(s) for s in re.findall(r'C+', st))
print "first _max : ",max(len(s) for s in re.findall(r'C+', st))
```

Output:

```
counts_of_C : [4, 9, 4, 7, 6]
first_max_value_of_C :  9
```

What I want is to find the **second maximum** count of "C" (second most consecutive occurrence of C here is **7**).

I can statically get this value from count list here, but I am looking for any other way to do this.

Comment: `sorted( [4, 9, 4, 7, 6] )[1]`

Comment: What if the maximum appears twice, e.g. `[4, 9, 4, 9, 6]`?

Comment: @AlexHall In the case of repeated maximums, the result has to depend on your own specific requirement, doesn't it?

Comment: @AlexHall no problem with that.but looking direct solution not like sorting the count list and finding 2nd place value

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi that's not an answer. Should it return 9 or 6?

Comment: @mikeqfu don't know why you're saying that, I'm asking what OP's specific requirement is.

Comment: @AlexHall I want  second most maximum count of "C" from the string which is 7 here

Comment: @furas It should be last second sorted(list)[-2]

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi I'm asking about my example where there is no 7.

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi you are right - it sorts in different order :) Or I would need `reverse=True` .

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the second maximum count by sorting a set:

```
print "counts_of_C :",sorted(set(len(s) for s in re.findall(r'C+', st)))[-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You execute regexp operation twice, while you could do it only one.
You can reuse list of occurrences, sort it and print first, second etc. element of this sorted list of occurrences.

```py
st = 'SSSSEEEECCCCEECCCCCCCCCSSSSEEECCCCSSSSSSSEEESSCCCCCCCSEESSSSCCCCCCSSEEEE'
import re
occurrences = [len(s) for s in re.findall(r'C+', st)]
sorted_ = sorted(occurrences, reverse=True)
print "counts_of_C : %s"% occurrences
print "first _max %d, second highest: %d" % (sorted_[0], sorted_[1])
```